# unknown margin when not generated by jquery

Tags: jquery, css, forms

i am trying to build something like this form:

https://jsfiddle.net/zycyuyrz/

The problem is that even if the html code is the same for html rows and also the jquery generated html rows, they appear different. Does someone knows what is this about?

**html:**

```
<div class="container">
    <fieldset id="formbuilder">
        <legend>Shopping list</legend>

        <p>Some text with some more text, describing the multiple shopping list.</p>

        <div class="form-container" id="form-container">

            <div class="list-item" id="list-item-1">
                <label class="sku-label" for="sku-1">SKU - 1</label>
                <input class="sku-input" type="text" id="sku-1" name="sku1" />
                <label class="qty-label" for="q-1">Qty</label>
                <input class="qty-input" type="text" id="q-1" name="q1" />
                <input class="btn-ver" type="button" name="verify1" value="Verify if available" />
                <input class="btn-rem" type="button" name="remove1" value="Remove (-)" />
            </div>

            <div class="list-item" id="list-item-2">
                <label class="sku-label" for="sku-2">SKU - 2</label>
                <input class="sku-input" type="text" id="sku-2" name="sku2" />
                <label class="qty-label" for="q-2">Qty</label>
                <input class="qty-input" type="text" id="q-2" name="q2" />
                <input class="btn-ver" type="button" name="verify2" value="Verify if available" />
                <input class="btn-rem" type="button" name="remove2" value="Remove (-)" />
            </div>

        </div>

    </fieldset>
        <input type="button" value="Send all to cart" class="btm-btn" id="send-to-cart" />
        <input type="button" value="Add new product (+)" class="btm-btn" id="add" />

</div>
```

**js:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var intId = $('#form-container .list-item').length + 1;
        var fWrapper = $("<div class=\"list-item\" id=\"list-item-" + intId + "\"></div>");

        var fLabelSku = $("<label class=\"sku-label\" for=\"sku-" + intId + "\">SKU - " + intId + "</label>");
        var fInputSku = $("<input class=\"sku-input\" type=\"text\" id=\"sku-" + intId + "\" name=\"sku" + intId + "\" />");
        var fLabelQty = $("<label class=\"qty-label\" for=\"q-" + intId + "\">Qty</label>");
        var fInputQty = $("<input class=\"qty-input\" type=\"text\" id=\"q-" + intId + "\" name=\"q" + intId + "\" />");
        var fBtnVerify = $("<input class=\"btn-ver\" type=\"button\" name=\"verify" + intId + "\" value=\"Verify if available\" />");
        var fBtnRemove = $("<input class=\"btn-rem\" type=\"button\" name=\"remove" + intId + "\" value=\"Remove (-)\" />");


        fWrapper.append(fLabelSku);
        fWrapper.append(fInputSku);
        fWrapper.append(fLabelQty);
        fWrapper.append(fInputQty);
        fWrapper.append(fBtnVerify);
        fWrapper.append(fBtnRemove);

        $('#form-container').append(fWrapper);



    });
});
```

**css:**

```
.container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.btm-btn {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.qty-input {
    width: 30px;
}

.list-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: The HTML has whitespace between the elements, you don't have any space between them in the jQuery code.

Comment: @MyvRO i have created jsfiddle using your code as in question and it looks same as you have given in fiddle so where is the problem dude .?? here is the jsfiddle i have created **https://jsfiddle.net/2xffxpvv/**

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara Your fiddle is like my answer, not like the OP's question.

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara the problem was that in the original post i had a space between row elements, what you created with jsfiddle is the answer for the problem. thanks

Comment: @Barmar dude i just have copy paste the css js and html part of the MyvRO's question and i have nothing changed so this thing is already working there might some other issue

Comment: @Barmar then it's the MyvRO's mistake that he changed the code in question because i have tried what is shown in question

Comment: @HimeshAadeshara There have been no edits to the question. I think you just made a mistake and copied from my answer instead of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding any spacing between the elements in the jQuery code, like you do in the original HTML. Put `fWrapper.append(" ");` between the elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    var intId = $('#form-container .list-item').length + 1;
    var fWrapper = $("<div class=\"list-item\" id=\"list-item-" + intId + "\"></div>");

    var fLabelSku = $("<label class=\"sku-label\" for=\"sku-" + intId + "\">SKU - " + intId + "</label>");
    var fInputSku = $("<input class=\"sku-input\" type=\"text\" id=\"sku-" + intId + "\" name=\"sku" + intId + "\" />");
    var fLabelQty = $("<label class=\"qty-label\" for=\"q-" + intId + "\">Qty</label>");
    var fInputQty = $("<input class=\"qty-input\" type=\"text\" id=\"q-" + intId + "\" name=\"q" + intId + "\" />");
    var fBtnVerify = $("<input class=\"btn-ver\" type=\"button\" name=\"verify" + intId + "\" value=\"Verify if available\" />");
    var fBtnRemove = $("<input class=\"btn-rem\" type=\"button\" name=\"remove" + intId + "\" value=\"Remove (-)\" />");


    fWrapper.append(fLabelSku);
    fWrapper.append(" ");
    fWrapper.append(fInputSku);
    fWrapper.append(" ");
    fWrapper.append(fLabelQty);
    fWrapper.append(" ");
    fWrapper.append(fInputQty);
    fWrapper.append(" ");
    fWrapper.append(fBtnVerify);
    fWrapper.append(" ");
    fWrapper.append(fBtnRemove);

    $('#form-container').append(fWrapper);



  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.btm-btn {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.qty-input {
  width: 30px;
}
.list-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <fieldset id="formbuilder">
    <legend>Shopping list</legend>

    <p>Some text with some more text, describing the multiple shopping list.</p>

    <div class="form-container" id="form-container">

      <div class="list-item" id="list-item-1">
        <label class="sku-label" for="sku-1">SKU - 1</label>
        <input class="sku-input" type="text" id="sku-1" name="sku1" />
        <label class="qty-label" for="q-1">Qty</label>
        <input class="qty-input" type="text" id="q-1" name="q1" />
        <input class="btn-ver" type="button" name="verify1" value="Verify if available" />
        <input class="btn-rem" type="button" name="remove1" value="Remove (-)" />
      </div>

      <div class="list-item" id="list-item-2">
        <label class="sku-label" for="sku-2">SKU - 2</label>
        <input class="sku-input" type="text" id="sku-2" name="sku2" />
        <label class="qty-label" for="q-2">Qty</label>
        <input class="qty-input" type="text" id="q-2" name="q2" />
        <input class="btn-ver" type="button" name="verify2" value="Verify if available" />
        <input class="btn-rem" type="button" name="remove2" value="Remove (-)" />
      </div>

    </div>

  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="Send all to cart" class="btm-btn" id="send-to-cart" />
  <input type="button" value="Add new product (+)" class="btm-btn" id="add" />

</div>
```

Comment: thanks it seems that the browser actually care about the endlines

Comment: Line breaks are treated like a space. So it's the difference between `<input><label>` and `<input> <label>`

Comment: @Barmar again i have created using the question again and here it is **https://jsfiddle.net/yy775wj7/** check this

Comment: And if you run that code, you can see a difference when you click on "Add new product". The added lines are shorter than the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

- Added default styles
- Added:  `.list-item:nth-of-type(n+3) input { margin-right: 5px; }`
- Added additional whitespace to the text of `<label>`s

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add').click(function() {
    var intId = $('#form-container .list-item').length + 1;
    var fWrapper = $('<div class="list-item" id="list-item-' + intId + '"></div>');

    var fLabelSku = $('<label class="sku-label" for="sku-' + intId + '">SKU - ' + intId + '&nbsp;</label>');
    var fInputSku = $('<input class="sku-input" type="text" id="sku-' + intId + '" name="sku' + intId + '">');
    var fLabelQty = $('<label class="qty-label" for="q-' + intId + '">Qty </label>');
    var fInputQty = $('<input class="qty-input" type="text" id="q-' + intId + '" name="q' + intId + '"/>');
    var fBtnVerify = $('<input class="btn-ver" type="button" name="verify' + intId + '" value="Verify if available" />');
    var fBtnRemove = $('<input class="btn-rem" type="button" name="remove' + intId + '" value="Remove (-)" />');


    fWrapper.append(fLabelSku);
    fWrapper.append(fInputSku);
    fWrapper.append(fLabelQty);
    fWrapper.append(fInputQty);
    fWrapper.append(fBtnVerify);
    fWrapper.append(fBtnRemove);

    $('#form-container').append(fWrapper);



  });
});
```

```css
/* Default */

/*=-=-=-=-=-=-*/

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 16px/1.45'Tahoma';
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*=-=-=-=-=-=-*/

/* Optional */

/*=-=-=-=-=-=-*/

#formbuilder > * {
  padding: 5px;
}
input::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -2px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
input[type="button"] {
  padding: 0 2px;
}
/*=-=-=-=-=-=-*/

.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.btm-btn {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.qty-input {
  width: 30px;
}
.list-item {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Required */

/*=-=-=-=-=-=-*/

.list-item:nth-of-type(n+3) input {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
/*=-=-=-=-=-=-*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <fieldset id="formbuilder">
    <legend>Shopping list</legend>
    <p>Some text with some more text, describing the multiple shopping list.</p>
    <div class="form-container" id="form-container">
      <div class="list-item" id="list-item-1">
        <label class="sku-label" for="sku-1">SKU - 1</label>
        <input class="sku-input" type="text" id="sku-1" name="sku1" />
        <label class="qty-label" for="q-1">Qty</label>
        <input class="qty-input" type="text" id="q-1" name="q1" />
        <input class="btn-ver" type="button" name="verify1" value="Verify if available" />
        <input class="btn-rem" type="button" name="remove1" value="Remove (-)" />
      </div>
      <div class="list-item" id="list-item-2">
        <label class="sku-label" for="sku-2">SKU - 2</label>
        <input class="sku-input" type="text" id="sku-2" name="sku2" />
        <label class="qty-label" for="q-2">Qty</label>
        <input class="qty-input" type="text" id="q-2" name="q2" />
        <input class="btn-ver" type="button" name="verify2" value="Verify if available" />
        <input class="btn-rem" type="button" name="remove2" value="Remove (-)" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="button" value="Send all to cart" class="btm-btn" id="send-to-cart" />
  <input type="button" value="Add new product (+)" class="btm-btn" id="add" />
</div>
```